# SPRESENSEのデジタル録音時の拡張ボードの改造

Tags: spresense

SPRESENSEのページ「2.12.2. アナログとデジタルの切り替え方法」で，アナログマイク録音からデジタルマイク録音に変える方法として，2つの手順（R49とR50の改造とJP１４の改造）が示されていますが，これは両方しないとデジタルマイクへの変換ができないということでしょうか？　別の言い方に言い換えると，R49とR50の改造でデジタルマイクの設定にして，JP14の設定で，あるチャンネルだけアナログマイクの設定にしたら，そのチャンネルは
アナログマイクとして録音できるのでしょうか？

そのページの説明に「マイクチャンネルごとにアナログとデジタルの選択使用が可能です。」と記述していたので，気になった次第です．

参考のURL
https://developer.sony.com/develop/spresense/docs/hw_docs_ja.html#_%E3%82%A2%E3%83%8A%E3%83%AD%E3%82%B0%E3%81%A8%E3%83%87%E3%82%B8%E3%82%BF%E3%83%AB%E3%81%AE%E5%88%87%E3%82%8A%E6%9B%BF%E3%81%88%E6%96%B9%E6%B3%95

Answer (score 0):

ソニーのSPRESENSEサポート担当です。

アナログマイク録音からデジタルマイク録音に変える方法としては、「[2.12.2. アナログマイクからデジタルマイク入力への切り替え方法](https://developer.sony.com/develop/spresense/docs/hw_docs_ja.html#_%E3%82%A2%E3%83%8A%E3%83%AD%E3%82%B0%E3%83%9E%E3%82%A4%E3%82%AF%E3%81%8B%E3%82%89%E3%83%87%E3%82%B8%E3%82%BF%E3%83%AB%E3%83%9E%E3%82%A4%E3%82%AF%E5%85%A5%E5%8A%9B%E3%81%B8%E3%81%AE%E5%88%87%E3%82%8A%E6%9B%BF%E3%81%88%E6%96%B9%E6%B3%95)」に示される以下の2つの手順の両方が必要です。

- R50を取り外し、R49に0Ωをマウント（またはジャンパ線などでショートする）。
- JP14の上下の半田ランドをジャンパ線などでショートする。

またドキュメントに「マイクチャンネルごとにアナログとデジタルの選択使用が可能です。」との記載がございましたが、各チャンネルごとに別々に設定を変更した場合には十分な性能が得られない可能性がございます。全てのチャンネルをアナログマイクまたはデジタルマイク入力に設定することを推奨いたします。

今後ともSPRESENSEをどうぞよろしくお願いいたします。

SPRESENSEサポートチーム